# android textpaint is not looking like textview with same parameters

Tags: android, textview

Im trying to make my `TextPaint` to look exectly like `TextView`, however TextView's text is always little bit bigger then text which is drawed with `TextPaint`.

TextView text:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:text="some text"
     />
```

TextPaint text:

```
    int textSize = 20;
    paint = new TextPaint();
    paint.setTextSize(textSize*density);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Could you post details about your variable `density` ?

Comment: my density is: `density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the size to pixels in the second listing:

```
int size = 20; //20dp

int pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                          size, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```